# How to remove columns which have zero sum from list of files

Tags: r, automation, pca

Below is the code for applying PCA on multiple dataframes country wise stored in myfiles.

```
## Get file names for a working directory ###
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")

## Read files ###
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.csv)

### Name the files ###

names(myfiles)<-c("mCRC_2015_Q1","mCRC_2015_Q2","mCRC_2015_Q3","mCRC_2015_Q4")

##### to check the names of the columns #######
names(myfiles$mCRC_2015_Q1)

##### to change the names of the columns ######

colnames = c("Insufficient efficacy","Issues around safety/tolerability","Inconvenient dosage regimen/administration","Price issues","Not reimbursed","Not included on hospital/government medicines formulary","Insufficient clinical data available for acceptance","Previously used for this patient","Prescription only possible in selected cases with detailed justification to authorities / payers ","I don’t have enough scientific information about it","Lack of experience in this setting","Involved in clinical trial with other drugs","Patient not appropriate for Targeted therapy","Patient not appropriate for cetuximab (Erbitux)","Others","Country") 


for (i in seq_along(myfiles)){
  colnames(myfiles[[i]]) <- colnames
}

##### Delete all those columns which have zero sum from each dataframe #####
for(i in 1:length(myfiles)){

  myfiles[[i]] <- myfiles[[i]][,which(!lapply(myfiles,FUN = function(x){colSums(x!=0)>0}))]

}

####### Run PCA for each dataframe country wise ####
Myfiles<- split(myfiles, myfiles$Country)
for(i in 1:length(Myfiles)){
  assign(paste0("pca", i), prcomp(Myfiles[[i]][which(names(myfiles)!="Country")], center=T, scale.=T))
}
```

These are the problems I am facing:
1) How can I delete all those columns which have only zero value.
2) How can we apply prcomp command on each dataframe countrywise(country is   one of the variable in the dataframes)
3) From the loadings matrix how can I get top 4 most correlated variables(irrespective of sign) for each dataframe.

Comment: That is too many questions.  One at a time, please.

Comment: @RichardScriven Please answer first one..! Thanks !

Comment: @Kavya can you give an example data? it will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: @Learner Here is the sample of data- http://i.stack.imgur.com/rsIqM.png

Comment: @Kavya in r, use dput and then post it in your question

Comment: @Kavya   look if this helps ? YOURdata[, colSums(abs(YOURdata)) != 0]  change the YOURdata with the name of your data frame

Answer (score 0):

My answer to question1, how to remove columns in a data.frame which have only zero as values:

```
exampledat <- data.frame( zero = rep(0,20), one= rep(1, 20), 
                       two = rep(1, 20),
                       mixed = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                       zeroagain = rep(0,20))

del_zero_cols <- function(datafr){
  datafr[,apply(datafr,2, function(value) any(value!=0, na.rm=TRUE))]
}

del_zero_cols(exampledat)
```

Comment: Thanks for this!! But my question is how can I apply the same thing for multiple dataframes stored in a list.

Comment: I gave you a function del_zero_cols() that you can easily apply to all list members using lapply().

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. I would do something like this for processing the values:

```
myfiles <- 
  list(
    q1 = data.frame(r_1 = rep(0, times = 3), r_2  = c(0,0,1), country = c(LETTERS[1:3])),
    q2 = data.frame(r_1 = rep(0, times = 3), r_2  = c(0,0,0), country = c(LETTERS[1:3])),
    q2 = data.frame(r_1 = rep(0, times = 3), r_2  = c(1,0,0), country = c(LETTERS[1:3]))
  )

# Merge the dataframes into one
merged_myfiles = do.call(rbind, myfiles)
merged_myfiles$file = gsub("\\.[0-9]+$", "", rownames(merged_myfiles))

# Clean columns that are all 0
cleaned_data = merged_myfiles[,!sapply(merged_myfiles, function(col) all(col == 0))]

# The by is a neat base function that allows you to do things on subsets
# the output is a list
by(cleaned_data, cleaned_data$country, function(df){
  mean(df$r_2)
})

# Used dplyr for grouping analyses
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
cleaned_data %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  do({
    data.frame(mean = mean(.$r_2), file = .$file[1])
  })
```

The `by` option gives you:

```
cleaned_data$country: A
[1] 0.3333333
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
cleaned_data$country: B
[1] 0
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
cleaned_data$country: C
[1] 0.3333333
```

While the `dplyr` gives:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: country [3]

  country      mean   file
   <fctr>     <dbl> <fctr>
1       A 0.3333333     q1
2       B 0.0000000     q1
3       C 0.3333333     q1
```

For selecting the maximum `prcomp` outputs I would suggest the following approach:

```
prcomp(USArrests) %>% 
  extract("rotation") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  abs() %>% 
  order(decreasing = TRUE) %>% 
  extract(1:4) %>% 
  data.frame(row = . %% ncol(USArrests),
             col = ceiling(. / ncol(USArrests)))
```

The original `prcomp(USArrests)$rotation` looks like this:

```
                PC1         PC2         PC3         PC4
Murder   0.04170432 -0.04482166  0.07989066 -0.99492173
Assault  0.99522128 -0.05876003 -0.06756974  0.03893830
UrbanPop 0.04633575  0.97685748 -0.20054629 -0.05816914
Rape     0.07515550  0.20071807  0.97408059  0.07232502
```

and the output from the magrittr pipes shows exactly what variables are of interest:

```
   . row col
1  2   2   1
2 13   1   4
3  7   3   2
4 12   0   3
```